# SQL select row where SUM of a column is greatest (with two fields in GROUP BY)

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Here's my basic query (SQL Server):

```
SELECT projectID, businessID, sum(number) AS summ
FROM table
GROUP BY projectID, businessID
ORDER BY projectID, sum(number) DESC
```

which produces a table like so:

```
         Project ID      Business ID    Summ
              1              1           63
              1              2           32 
              1              3            6
              2              3           45
              2              1           44
              2              2            3
```

I want to grab the project ID and business ID where the Summ column is greatest for each project ID. So rows 1 and 4 in the example given. How can I tweak the original query to do this?

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL Server?  MySQL? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: You want just one row where the value corresponding to sum column is greatest?

Comment: Dan, SQL Server. Mayank, I want every row where the sum column is greatest for each project ID.

Comment: Please check this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

Comment: If you're going to attempt to answer the question, then post an answer. Your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions:

```
SELECT projectID,
       businessID,
       summ
  FROM(SELECT projectID,
              businessID,
              SUM(number) AS summ,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY projectID
                                     ORDER BY SUM(number) DESC) AS rn
        FROM table
       GROUP
          BY projectID,
             businessID
      ) t
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER
    BY projectID;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This returns every row the the original query did, with a new column rn which has a value of 1 for every row.

Comment: The original post had a small mistake. Can you try again. Here is a sqlfiddle exampe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/887d2/7

Comment: That's it! Partitioning by both projectID and businessID was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you might have ties and want to return both rows, you should use:

```
select * from
    (select projectID, businessID
      , sum(number) as Tot
      , max(sum(number)) over (partition by projectID) as MSum
      from Table
    group by projectID, businessID)
a
where a.tot = a.Msum
```

Comment: You can calculate an analytic function of the result of an aggregate function?  It makes sense that you can, but I didn't know.  Cool.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second aggregation or an analytic function.  Here's a way to do it with a second aggregation:

```
WITH sums as (
  SELECT projectID, businessID, sum(number) AS summ
  FROM table
  GROUP BY projectID, businessID
)
SELECT sums.projectId, sums.businessId, sums.summ
FROM
  (
    SELECT projectID, MAX(summ) as ms
    FROM sums
    GROUP BY projectID
  ) ms
  JOIN sums
    ON sums.projectId = ms.projectId AND sums.summ = ms.ms
```

You would need this approach on a system that doesn't support analytic functions, which, luckily for you, does not include SQL Server.